# Powershell: message-box crashes do while loop

Tags: powershell

I have this simple script that just gets path an verifies if it exists.

```
function getPaths(){

        $pathFromCMS = Read-Host "Please set the path for the copy files"
        $pathToCMS = Read-Host "Please set the path to your CMS application"

        if ((Test-Path -Path $pathFromCMS ) -and (Test-Path -Path $pathToCMS )){
            Return $True
        }
        else{
            [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('You have provided wrong path!')
            Return $False
        }
}
do{}while (! (getPaths) -eq $True)

echo "Hello there"
```

The problem is with the MessageBox::Show function. It somehow makes the loop stop when entering wrong paths. When I change it just for Write-Host "You have provided wrong path!" everything works fine. Can someone explain why this happens pls ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show` method returns a value, and that breaks your loop condition. You can suppress the return value by piping to `Out-Null`:

```
[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('You have provided wrong path!') | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 0):

A MessageBox can have different buttons on it (e.g. YES/NO) and so is shown synchronously to allow you to capture what the user clicks.  For example:

```
$preference = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Do you like MessageBoxes?', "MessageBox Preference", [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::YesNo)
```

In your case, even if you only want 'OK', it is still a good idea for it to wait, since the user always needs to manually dismiss it, unlike the output from `Write-Host`.

Answer (score -1):

It is because there is nothing in your do{} block to be executed while the condition is satisfied.

What you want is:

```
do{(getPaths)}while ((getPaths) -ne $True)
```

Comment: That will call getPaths twice no mjatter what.

Comment: Then how about: $bool = $False
do{
$bool = (getPaths)
}while (($bool) -ne $true)